# Как отфильтровать запрос так, чтобы вывелись посты по всем совпадениям тегов many to many, django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, many-to-many, queryset

Как сделать запрос так, чтобы вывелись посты, которые совпадают по всем тегам, а не только по одному совпадению.

`view.py`:

```
class CostTags:

def get_tags(self):
    return TagsNotebook.objects.all()

def get_cost(self):
    return CostNotebook.objects.all()

class Filter(CostTags, ListView):
template_name = 'poligloty_site/notebook.html'
context_object_name = 'notebook'
def get_queryset(self):
    tags = self.request.GET.getlist("tag")
    queryset = Notebook.objects.filter(tags__in=tags).distinct('id')
    return queryset
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns=[
path('', SborkiView.as_view(), name="notebook"),
path("filter/", Filter.as_view(), name='filter'),]
```

`models.py`:

```
class TagsNotebook(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField('Тег', max_length=50)
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=63, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag

class Notebook(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=50)
    image_intro = models.ImageField('Image_intro', upload_to='intro/notebook')
    anons = models.CharField('Кратко', max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField('Описание')
    date = models.DateTimeField('Публикация', auto_now_add=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("TagsNotebook", verbose_name='Теги')
    cost = models.ForeignKey('CostNotebook', verbose_name='Категория стоимости', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Ноутбук'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ноутбуки'
```

`sidebar.html`:

```
<form action="{% url 'filter' %}" method="get">
      <div class="card mb-4">

                    <div class="card-header">Tags</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                                    {% for tags in view.get_tags %}
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checked" name="tag" value="{{ tags.id }}">
                                        <a href="#">{{ tags.tag }}</a>
                                    </li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<button type="submit" >Search</button>
</form>
```

Получаются запросы:

```
 INNER JOIN "mypc_site_notebook_tags"
 ON ("mypc_site_notebook"."id" = "mypc_site_notebook_tags"."notebook_id")
 WHERE "mypc_site_notebook_tags"."tagsnotebook_id" IN (2, 4)
```

Таким образом выводятся посты с тегами 2 или 4, а мне нужно, чтобы выводились с тегами 2 И 4.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Так себе идея, но можно получить 2 queryset c тегом 2 и 4, а потом объединить: queryset = query_set_1 | query_set_2

Comment: Способ, конечно, не рациональный(по моему мнению), но мне помогло, спасибо!

Comment: Возможно этот ответ вам поможет   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52168690/django-filter-queryset-by-multiple-id

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) функцию для создания запроса. Например:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce
from django.db.models import Q

class Filter(CostTags, ListView):
    template_name = 'poligloty_site/notebook.html'
    context_object_name = 'notebook'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        tags = self.request.GET.getlist("tag")
        queryset = Notebook.objects.filter(
            reduce(operator.and_, (Q(tag__pk=tag) for tag in tags)
        )

        return queryset
```